# Why are only certain terrain texture colors being blacked out?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I am updating my lighting and can not figure out why specific terrain textures show up as black? I know they are actually showing because at the right angles on a hill or mountain it can be seen. So I believe its a lighting issue I just cant find any solutions.

[image]
[image]

I have verified the texture isnt missing